# Attempting to install ubuntu 11.10

Tags: system-installation

I installed version 9 sometime ago and since have forgotten the process for partitioning, or the layout is different.

I have 5 partitions but only have windows xp installed on the pc in question with that being the one of those 5 partitions which is ntfs 34444 mb its - a 40gig hard-drive.

My first question is... is there a way to get a screen shot of the partitioner when I am running the demo session straight from disc... these 5 partitions are fragmenting the other 4ish gig needed to install.. I get an error message which says go back and make sure 1 partition has at least 2.5 gig or so. But I have no idea what I am supposed to set these remaining 4 partitions to in order to proceed.. I have read up on install guides and understand that one must be "/" root and another as swap... but to no avail thus far have the correct combo.

A few screen shots will no doubt help you guys answer as I'm baffled as to what specific details to give as each one has various settings on inspection, and I don't really feel like writing it all down manually then posting specs for each one

---

Edit: Thanks for the reply, very helpful

that is the screenshot from gpart http://i1098.photobucket.com/albums/g369/Ryan_Onessence/Screenshotat2012-03-25220041.png

and this is from the installer http://i1098.photobucket.com/albums/g369/Ryan_Onessence/Screenshotat2012-03-25220539.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a screenshot tool in the livecd. Click the button in the top left to open the dash - start typing screenshot - it should appear. If you can't find it then the PrtSc button will take a whole desktop shot.

To get a shot of the partitions there is no need to start the install procedure - search for gparted in dash and take a shot of that instead.

Comment: Cheers! I have edited the question with screenshot links (not sure how to embed)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing on the linux partitions now then I would be inclined to start again.

The gparted screenshot shows some sort of error on the ntfs partition - boot windows and run the chkdsk tools on it.

Once you've done that reboot the livecd, run gparted again.

Delete the linux and linux-swap partitions, shrink the ntfs one to give enough space for ubuntu.

Then run the installer again - I believe there is a use free space option.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall